# Powerapps gallery to show 2 sharepoint list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection

I need help on powereapps gallery. The idea is to show a summary of items on a gallery with feeding two sharepoint list data source (primary list ConsumableRecord & secondary list ConsumableWithdraw). To workaround i tried a collection -Summaryconsume. This is my formula for the gallery item property SummaryConsume and for screen onvisible is ClearCollect(SummaryConsume, ConsumableRecord, ConsumableWithdraw). I get the data but its shows one list after another it doesn't seem to show the relation. There is a column masterID in the secondary list which allows the primary list to relate and pull the related line items. How can i related these into the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use search or lookup functions to retrive the children records by using the masterID

For More details on how to use search or lookup functions check the [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)